# WebStorm - debugging a Jest test - abnormal amount of time before the breakpoint is hit

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, webstorm, ts-jest

I've got a typescript + jest (with ts-loader) set up.

Hitting the breakpoint in this sample test (the only test present in the project) takes a couple of minutes. This happens only in WebStorm. In VSCode with this configuration

```
 "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Jest Tests",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
                "--runInBand"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
        }
    ]
```

it was almost instant.

Debugging Jest tests in the CRA environment works just fine, even in WebStorm.

The test:

```
describe('Stuff', function () {
    it('should', function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true); // breakpoint
    });
});
```

The repo:
https://github.com/vlopp/jest-webstorm-testing

Please tell me what's wrong, and how I can minimize the abnormal time that WebStorm takes to debug tests.

## UPDATE

Throwing out ts-jest doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: just tried this in Webstorm 2019.3.1 - hitting a breakpoints takes about a second... I'm using **Jest** run configuration with **All Tests** scope. What Webstorm build is it, what Node.js version is used, what OS are you on?

Comment: @lena `node --version` reports `v13.2.0`. The system is `Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363`. WebStorm version is `2019.3.1`, build `#WS-193.5662.54`. An all-tests Jest configuration has the same issue for me.

Comment: can't reproduce using the same OS, Node.js and IDE build. must be smth specific to your setup. Do you have exception breakpoints enabled in **Run | View Breakpoints**?

Comment: please enable `js.debugger.wip.log` in *Registry* (**Help | Find action**, type `Registry...` to locate it) by setting it to path to some temporary file like `C:/tmp/wip.json`, recreate the issue and create a support ticket, providing this log along with your log folder zipped (**Help > Compress Logs and Show in Explorer**). Note that the debug log will be re-written on each debugger start, so it's important to copy the log right after reproducing the issue

Comment: @lena For future reference - the prolonged wait happens only if "Toggle Break on Exception" is enabled. I will post the log later as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue with *JavaScript Exception Breakpoints* enabled, please follow [WEB-28989](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28989) for updates